# dropdownlist is not showing the selecteditem from the database

Tags: c#, asp.net

am trying to get the selected item from the database, but its not displaying nothing
code behind:

```
 private void bindRows()
            {
                try
                {
                    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MainConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

                    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
                    connection.Open();



                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select id, message from Dropdown", connection);

                    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    reader.Close();

                    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select id, message from Dropdown", connection);
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    adapter.Fill(ds);

                    DdlRegister.DataSource = ds;
                    DdlRegister.DataTextField = "message";
                    DdlRegister.DataValueField = "id";
                    DdlRegister.DataBind();
                    DdlRegister.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("I Want", "0"));
                    connection.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {

                }
            }
```

code of buttonclick

```
 try
            {
                string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MainConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
                SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
                connection.Open();

                string selectCommand = "Insert into Register (name,designation,company,mobile,email,message) values(@name,@designation,@company,@mobile,@email,@message);";

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectCommand, connection);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtname.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@designation", txtdesignation.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@company", txtcompany.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mobile", txtmobile.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", txtemail.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@message", DdlRegister.SelectedItem.Text.Trim());

                int cnt = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (cnt > 0)
                {
                    ShowMessage("Registeration is done");

                }
                Response.Redirect("Index.aspx");

                connection.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
```

design

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DdlRegister" runat="server" CssClass="form-control ddl " OnSelectedIndexChanged="DdlRegister_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" >
 </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: swallowing all exceptions is bad

Comment: i have used a table named dropdown in mylittleadmin.. its not showing any values even "i want" also

Answer (score 0):

```
private void bindRows()
        {
            try
            {
                string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MainConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

                SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
                connection.Open();

                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select id, message from Dropdown", connection);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                adapter.Fill(ds);

                DdlRegister.DataSource = ds;
                DdlRegister.DataTextField = "message";
                DdlRegister.DataValueField = "id";
                DdlRegister.DataBind();
                DdlRegister.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("I Want", "0"));
                connection.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }
        }
```

Comment: <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="test.aspx.cs" Inherits="test" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
               <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" runat="server" >
                   
                </asp:DropDownList>
           </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

Comment: You should add bindRows() function in pageload and add id ,message in dropdown Table then it will be work properly

Comment: bindrows() is already there in page load inside postback and i have created the dropdown table with the id and message

Comment: what type of error is showing in your code. if you are able than send your all code with sql table and data

Comment: protected void DdlRegister_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DdlRegister.Text = DdlRegister.SelectedItem.Text;
        }                     am getting this error locally                                                    ''DdlRegister' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.

Comment: i got cleared that error locally but when i upload on website it doesnot work

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
string mainconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MY"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(mainconn);
        string sqlquery = "select * from [dbo].[sortcompany]";
        SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, sqlconn);
        sqlconn.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcomm);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        Company.ValueMember = "company_name";
        Company.DisplayMember = "company_name";
        Company.DataSource = dt;
```